# What does the term "ex tempore" mean?

Tags: terminology, history

I was going to give an answer and in this quotation about Werckmeister I encountered the term **ex tempore**.

[enter link description here](https://354f5231-1965-4276-8d19-34ef8dc9793c.filesusr.com/ugd/064a76_6a7e8ac8e7854e49b5138f10fefcb326.pdf)

I first thought this means memorizing and playing by heart.

*A pianist was therefore in the original sense of the word a composer, the
Handicraft dominated, independently a piece of music from different claves
together. His ability is to know "like the claves together sound. That is why he distinguishes himself by having the "nature of the piano.
From this it follows that the familiar separation between composer and interpreter belongs to the music thinking at the time Werckmeister was alien. It becomes clear that the ability of a Clavier-player, to master "piano and composition", is identical to the artisan ability of improvisation (**"ex tempore**"). Also on the ability of the transposition reveals "whether an organist has his piano in his head". The term "virtuoso" in the Baroque period is diametrically opposed to today's term. A virtuoso was after Kuhnau a musician who could "compose" **ex tempore** a piece of music itself. The one who could not improvise, was the beginning of the 18th
Century as a "musical quack".*

Now I suppose this rather means what is called in German: aus dem "Stegreif".

Comment: I'd put it, as in the text, as extemporisation, also known as improvisation.

Comment: Can we change that external link to something that might still be there next year, or something we can read without having to go off-site?

Comment: we can just take it away if you trust me that I know the source. The link is also added in the German wiki (but not in English)
https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andreas_Werckmeister and here:http://www.felbick.de/diverses

Answer (score 0):

As the quotation about Werckmeister suggests **ex tempore** also means improvisation.

(The German wiki site is more extended than the English:)

*In music Extempore since the 16th century refers to the free variation of a melody to a given voice (usually the bass part, see Generalbass), but also of ornaments that can delay the process. Et al in jazz, on the other hand, one speaks of improvisations.*

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extempore

But this is not all: It is not only improvisation in a solo or accompaniment of  well known tune, it means also to find the correct harmonization of a song we don't know and haven't heard before. Like in improvisation theater we don't know what the other part will be answering or where the journey is going.  So extempore I would compare with a snowboarder the falls free style downhill above rocks and avelanches without knowing where it will end, but it goes downwards.

While improvisation:

Usually a jazzer, thorough bass player, a soloist has a concept of a song in his mind. It can be compared with a snowboarder that runs down hill on a prepared piste.

Now here is a longer description found in  **Dictionary of Music and Musician**s

*EXTEMPORE PLAYING. The art of playing without [1]premeditation, the conception of the music and its rendering being simultaneous. The power of playing extempore evinces a very high degree of musical cultivation, as well as the possession of great natural gifts. Not only must the faculty of musical invention be present, but there must also be a perfect mastery over all mechanical difficulties, that the fingers may be able to render instantaneously what the mind conceives, as well as a thorough knowledge of the rules of harmony, counterpoint, and musical form, that the result may be symmetrical and complete.*

https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/A_Dictionary_of_Music_and_Musicians/Extempore_Playing